# Android debugging timeouts

Tags: android, debugging

My activity occasionally gets hung somewhere in it's looper.

From the log I can see an eventual timeout is logged, and then there's a win-death.

```
WARN/ActivityManager(1052): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{1234 {com.company.app/com.company.app.App}}
...
WARN/ActivityManager(1052): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{1234 {com.company.app/com.company.app.App}}
...
INFO/Process(416): Sending signal. PID: 416 SIG: 9
INFO/WindowManager(1052): WIN DEATH: Window{1234 com.company.app/com.company.app.App paused=false}
```

How can I debug this?  Can I get a stack-trace when it's interrupted?